# How to detect when a Chrome extension is installed for the first time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension and I need it to detect the very first time they install the extension (not just update it) so `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` won't work. I need to ask them (the users) a question the first time they install it and store it in `localStorage`. e.g. `localStorage.setItem("name", prompt("What is your name?"))`. You get the idea. My problem is just getting it to do it the first time it's installed and not do it every time it installs an update.

Comment: you may test [OnInstalledReason](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-OnInstalledReason) the first parameter of [onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled). When reason is **install** you can go on...

Comment: @wOxxOm why did you close this question because it was a duplicate of "Detect Chrome extension first run / update" and I thought I made it very clear that I need it only when it is installed for the first time, not updated LOL. Already got an answer so it's fine that it is closed but I thought that was pretty funny.

Comment: That topic shows an example for both scenarios. That is also the correct solution, unlike the one posted here, which will fail if the storage is cleaned by a utility or by the user manually via devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. I didn't think about that. I will look at that answer and see if it answers the question better (it probably will).

Comment: @wOxxOm I was just reading through this again and realized that for my problem the answer here is actually exactly what I need. If the storage was cleaned I would need to collect it again. I've learned a lot more about development since I first asked this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to read the stored value, and assume that if it doesn't exist it's the first time.

For example:

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("name")) {
  // that's the first time the extension runs
} else {
  // not the first time
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought of doing that before but for some reason I was thinking it wouldn't work cause there would be an error because it wouldn't exist yet (the localStorage).